# How does sign extension from signed char to sign int works?

Tags: c, type-conversion, signed

Why does a `255` value represented by a signed char, get converted to `-1` with an integer? I see a `mov sbl` instruction being used by `x86` to convert a signed `char` to a signed `int`, but why does it convert in the way it does now?

Comment: Please show your example code if you want answers.

Comment: You mean unsigned char? Signed char only goes up to 128. 255 as signed char is actually -1.

Comment: Are you sure your platform's `signed char` can actually express the value 255?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming an 8-bit char, an object of type `signed char` can never have a value 255. When you assign 255 to such an object, it gets converted in an implementation-defined manner (which, in reality, is always reduction modulo 256 into the range). Thus, it *already* has value -1 at this point. Converting that to type `int` makes no change at all.

Comment: The word object is used intentionally; it has a different meaning from "variable" and is the correct word in the language of the C standard for what I'm referring to. Please don't make seemingly-trivial edits that change the meaning of an answer to something different or less precise.

Answer (score 0):

Sign extension works by checking the high bit of the value and extending from there. 255 is all 1's as unsigned therefore when it's sign extended it's padded with 1's. All 1's in signed integer format is -1.

I noticed you said 255 as signed char. Max value of signed char is actually 127. If you do

```
char a = 255;
```

you will actually get -1 in some compilers. Unsigned char can hold 255 though.

Comment: @CarlNorum Thanks fat fingered the keyboard :P

Answer (score 0):

The instruction `movsb{w,l,q}` looks at the "top bit" in the byte, and fills the remaining bits of the word (16, 32 or 64 bits) with that value.

The sister instruction to this is `movzb{w,l,q}`, which zero extends (that is, does an "unsigned extension".

In 64-bit x86, 32-bit operations automatically zero-fills the upper 32-bit, so to extend a 32-bit value to 64-bit, the compiler will add an `movslq` to extend the 32-bit number to 64-bits.

There is also `movswl` and `movswq` to extend 16-bit registers to 32 and 64 bits respectively.